# Read lines from a tab delimited text file to make a new file using bash

Tags: bash, csv

I have a large tab delimited text (.txt) file with multiple lines. What I would like to do is take each line from this txt file and make it its own individual file.

for example, if my text file were to look like this:

```
11111111
22222222
33333333
```

I would like to have three text files, one that reads "11111111", another that reads "22222222", and another that reads "33333333".

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to start. I know how to do the opposite and read individual files into a one big file. Where I think I'm getting stuck is I'm not sure how to read through multiple lines. Do I make each line a variable? How do I stop at the end of the line? etc.

Comment: what sort of names do you want on your separate files. AND what is the rule to generate a new file? `if (prevLine!=currentLine) { make_new_file currentLine } prevLine=currentLine ...`? Good luck.

Comment: Did you try any of the answers? Did they work for you, or do you need any additional clarification?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious way to do this would be to use `split`:

```
split -l 1 file out
```

This splits `file` into separate files, `outaa`, `outab` and `outac`, each containing one line of the input file.

The default length of the suffixes is 2 but you can change it using the `-a` switch. For example,
`split -a 1 -l 1 file out` would create files `outa`, `outb` and `outc` instead.

Take a look at [`man split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) to see more options that you can use to control the output.

Comment: I think this is most likely to work but when I try this it creates one output file (outa with the last line aka 33333333). I think this may be because I created the the text file using excel? When I `cat` the original file it also only shows the last line...any advice with how to proceed?

Comment: So you made the files on in Excel on Windows and now you're trying to split them in Linux? It sounds like you have a problem with line endings (which differ between the two). You should try running `dos2unix` on your file first, to convert the line endings.

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
file=$1
i=0
while read line    // reads file line by line
do
echo $line > "file$i" //writes each line to a file until last line is reached
((i++))
done < aline.txt
```

if the contents of file is the same as the one you provided, you will have the following files:

```
file0 --> 11111111
file1 --> 22222222
file3 --> 33333333
```